# Fixing Communications between Arduino and C++ Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, arduino, serial-port

I am having trouble communicating from C++ to Arduino using Serial. I have used the method discussed by Salil Kapur here: https://salilkapur.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/communicating-with-arduino-using-c/. I have adapted his strategy of writing directly to the Arduino's file using c++.For my specific task , I need to send a string of char’s (which are commands for the arduino to process) to the Arduino. I have already read the chars from a file in the C++ program, but for some reason, I am getting nothing from my Arduino Serial monitor when I send it over. I think that the baud rate might be the problem, but I am not positive. I will give you my code for specific help. If someone can advise me how to get the C++ to write the chars to the Serial monitor to be read:

```
C++:
#include
#include //For sleep()
#include //For FILE
#include //For ifstream
#include //For assert()
#include //For string
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   //Setting up the output to the Arduino
   FILE *arduino;
   arduino = fopen(“/dev/tty.usbmodem1411″,”w”);  //Declare the file in write mode
   if (arduino == NULL) perror (“Error opening file”);

   //Setting up the file input stream
   ifstream inFile (“input.txt”);
   assert(inFile.is_open());

   char input = '\0'; //Starts out as NULL

   while (input!= EOF) {
      fprintf(arduino,”%c “, input); //Writing to the file
      inFile >> input; //Getting the file input to make sure it isn’t the EOF
      sleep(1);
   }
   fclose(arduino);
}
```

Arduino Code:

```
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
   char input;
   if(Serial.available()) //If anything is in the Serial 
   {
      input=Serial.read();

      Serial.println(input); //Print out any input
   }
}
```

Sample input from input.txt:

> w a d s w d a a s d w

That string of characters will provide a direction (up, down, left, right) as per WASD.

Comment: Have you tried using a serial console (e.g. PuTTY) to talk to the Arduino?

Comment: My question was solved by using the boost asio library. It allowed me to read text from a .txt file and then send it over serial to the arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use the file handle to write data to a serial device, but it might be helpful to first try using the native Unix serial communication API as a sanity check.

Take a look at this post on todbot.com: [Arduino-serial: C code to talk to Arduino](http://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/)

The todbot.com post describes a general purpose program for talking to an Arduino over its serial connection. The source has a lot of code for getting settings from the command line, and is a bit intimidating because it's robust, but the business end of the serial communication is fairly straightforward if you want to see how he does it.

I wrote my own series of posts on the topic, with some light-weight code (in parts 3 and 4) that demonstrates how to do almost exactly what you're trying to do.

[How to read serial data from an Arduino in Linux with C: Part 1](http://chrisheydrick.com/2012/06/12/how-to-read-serial-data-from-an-arduino-in-linux-with-c-part-1/)

I hope something in those links help! Serial communication is hard, so don't beat yourself up too much if it's not going your way.